# ggplot change line color specified by x axis values

Tags: r, ggplot2

Code to reproduce:

```
myDat <- data.frame(Event = rep(c("Arrival", "Departure"), 3),
                AtNode = c("StationA", "StationA", "Track", "Track", "StationB", "StationB"),
                Lane = c("Lane1", "Lane1", "Lane2", "Lane2", "Lane1", "Lane1"),
                atTime = c(10, 12, 18, 20, 34, 36),
                Type = c("Station", "Station", "Track", "Track", "Station", "Station"),
                Train = 1 )
ggplot(data =myDat, aes(x = atTime, y=factor(AtNode, levels = unique(paste(myDat[order(myDat$atTime),"AtNode"]))), group = Train, colour = Lane ))+
  geom_point(data = myDat)+
  geom_path(data = myDat[which(!grepl(pattern = "Track", myDat$Type)),])
```

[image]

Now i need to project the two green points (Y = "Track") on the orange line and color the line between the projected points the same color as the points.

Expected result: (without the points (Y ="Track")

[image]

Thanks in advance for every hint or trick!

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

I don't think your output is the right way of showing what you want. You have `factors` on your `y-axis`, which means it ranges between 1 and 3.

Therefore, projecting a line there means nothing in terms of `y-axis` values.

For me, the correct way of showing your data would be like this

```
ggplot(data =myDat,
       aes(x = atTime, y=factor(AtNode, levels = unique(paste(myDat[order(myDat$atTime),"AtNode"]))), 
           group = AtNode, colour = Lane ))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line() +
  labs(y = 'AtNode')
```

[image]

However, to do it how you asked, you can do some simple trigonometry to project your line segment

```
x1 = 1 + tan(asin(2/sqrt(484)))*6 #y projection given x = 18
x2 = 1 + tan(asin(2/sqrt(484)))*8 #y projection given x = 20

foo = data.frame(x = c(18,20), y = c(x1, x2), Lane = "Lane2")

ggplot(data = myDat, aes(x = atTime, y=factor(AtNode, levels = unique(paste(myDat[order(myDat$atTime),"AtNode"]))), group = 1, colour = Lane ))+
  geom_path(data = myDat[which(!grepl(pattern = "Track", myDat$Type)),]) +
  geom_line(data = foo, aes(x = x, y = y, color = Lane), size = 1) +
  scale_y_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a quick solution to this, but you could do something like this:

```
myDat$AtNode <- factor(myDat$AtNode, levels = unique(paste(myDat[order(myDat$atTime),"AtNode"]))) #Generate factor here so we can use in imputation calculation

impute_rows <- which(myDat$Type == "Track") #Select rows to impute
slope_df <- myDat[impute_rows + c(-1,1), ] #Select rows before and after imputation to calculate slope

line <- lm(as.numeric(AtNode) ~ atTime, data = slope_df) #Get slope of line so we can do the calculations
df <- data.frame(x = myDat[impute_rows, "atTime"], y = myDat[impute_rows, "atTime"]*line$coefficients[["atTime"]] + line$coefficients[["(Intercept)"]], Lane = myDat[impute_rows,"Lane"], Train =  myDat[impute_rows,"Train"])

ggplot(data =myDat, aes(x = atTime, y=AtNode, group = Train, colour = Lane ))+
  geom_path(data = myDat[which(!grepl(pattern = "Track", myDat$Type)),]) + 
  geom_path(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y), size = 2) + 
  scale_y_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

The idea is as follows:

- Identify the rows you want to impute: `which()`
- Identify the rows before and after the ones to impute `slope_df`
- Using the rows before and after the desired values to impute generate equation of line you want to impute along (using the `slope_df`)
- Generate data based on the line `df <- data.frame(...)`

Note that you also need the `scale_y_discrete(drop = FALSE)` so that the `Track` level isn't removed from the plot.